# Auto-hide Floating Action Button in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to show scrollToTop button when user scrollToBottom and when user at top then only show scrollToBottom. How to manage the button please help me...this is my screenshot please help me how to manage these button.

[image]

**tab1.page.ts**

```
    <ion-content cache-view="false" (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart()" (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)"
  (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd()" [scrollEvents]="true">

  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
      <ion-fab-button *ngIf="showToolbar" (click)="ScrollToTop($event)">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup"></ion-icon>
      </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab>

    <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
      <ion-fab-button  (click)="ScrollToBottom($event)">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
      </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab>

</ion-content>
```

tab1.page.ts

```
 ScrollToTop(event){
    this.content.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((data)=>{
      if(this.content){
        //console.log(data);
       this.showToolbar = true;
      }
     });
    this.content.scrollToTop(1500);

  }
  ScrollToBottom(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(1500);
  }
  logScrollStart(){

   // console.log("logScrollStart : When Scroll Starts");
  }

  logScrolling(){


  }

  logScrollEnd(){
    this.content.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((data)=>{
      if(this.content){
        //console.log(data);
       this.showToolbar = true;
      }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```html
<ion-content cache-view="false" (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart()" (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)"
      (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd()" [scrollEvents]="true">

  <ion-fab *ngIf="showTop" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button *ngIf="showToolbar" (click)="ScrollToTop($event)">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>

  <ion-fab  *ngIf="showBottom" vertical="top" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button  (click)="ScrollToBottom($event)">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>

</ion-content>
```

and

```js
ScrollToTop(event){
  this.content.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((data)=>{
    if(this.content){
      //console.log(data);
      this.showToolbar = true;
    }
  });
  this.content.scrollToTop(1500);
  this.showBottom=true;
  this.showTop=false;
}

ScrollToBottom(){
  this.content.scrollToBottom(1500);
  this.showTop=true;
  this.showBottom=false;
}
```

Comment: this.showTop=true;  this.showBottom=false; how to set this variable

Comment: at  tab1.page.ts  right before constructor add : showTop=false;showBottom=true;